# jQuery Hide and Show Attr Src Image not switching as intended

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

so I searched around and edited a show/hide jquery code I found, and it works just fine except the html img attribute does not get replaced when I click on it.

My jQuery code:

```
<script> 
$(document).ready(function() {

    var button = $('#hideButton');

    //check the cookie when the page loads
    if ($.cookie('currentToggle') === 'hidden') {
        togglePanel(button, false);
    }
    else {
        togglePanel(button, true);
    }

    //handle the clicking of the show/hide toggle button
    button.click(function() {
        //toggle the panel as required, base on current state
        if (button.attr('src') === "images/expand.gif") {
            togglePanel($(this), true);
        }
        else {
            togglePanel($(this), false);
        }
    });

});

function togglePanel(button, show) {

    var panel = $('#panel');

    if (show) {
        panel.removeClass('hidden');
        button.attr('src','images/collapse.gif');
        $.cookie('currentToggle', '', { path: '/' });
    }
    else {
        panel.addClass('hidden');
        button.attr('src','images/expand.gif');
        $.cookie('currentToggle', 'hidden', { path: '/' });
    }
}
</script>
```

My HTML code:

```
<a id="hideButton" href="#"><img src="images/collapse.gif"></a>
<div id="panel">
    <p>
    Test
    </p>
</div>
```

When I look at my firebug console, it shows the a href src attribute changing like so "`<a ... src="extend.gif">`" but not the actual "`<img src="">`" element itself. How do I fix this? Thank you.

Comment: You're doing it the hard way. UI elements should use CSS backgrounds, not inline images. You can then change the image simply by swapping CSS class names.

Comment: As i said before, and will say again, don't just copy and paste someone else code. Even when you edit it, you will not understand what he was trying to accomplisch. Study the code and write the elements you need down.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Diodeus, I'll do that instead.

Answer (score 0):

to make your function work - you will want to change it to instead update the src attribute of the IMG element.  not the anchor tag... you can do that like so:

```
function togglePanel(button, show) {

    var panel = $('#panel');

    if (show) {
        panel.removeClass('hidden');
        button.find('img').attr('src','images/collapse.gif');
        $.cookie('currentToggle', '', { path: '/' });
    }
    else {
        panel.addClass('hidden');
        button.find('img').attr('src','images/expand.gif');
        $.cookie('currentToggle', 'hidden', { path: '/' });
    }
}
```

the .find('img') will return the child objects matching the selector of that parameter - for the element you call it on... in this case the anchor tag stored in your variable button...

a few things i would like to note:  swapping src attributes might be effective, but you will notice a "flashing" on slower internet connections or as the image sizes gets larger.  this is because you are actually having the user make a request and load that image.

the recommended way would be to do this like Diodeus said - utilizing css classes and my preference would be image sprites - that will negate the 'flashing' and minimize resource load times after the DOM has completed loading.

EDIT:

RafH has a good point! - you will also have to update the if conditional ( i overlooked ) to check the image source - not the anchors source.  as he suggested

Comment: Thanks for the tips Joe. I kind of got the css working already, though the initial collapse image disappeared with a css background. So I'm going to try to figure that out first and if it works, then I'll just go with the css one.

Answer (score 0):

button refers to the a tag, if you want to change the img src then you need to use the correct selector :

```
$('img',button).attr('src', 'whatever.gif');
```

In your code :

```
if (button.attr('src') === "images/expand.gif") {
```

should be :

```
if ($('img', button).attr('src') === "images/expand.gif") {
```

You need to do the same thing in the togglePanel function too.

Comment: RafH good point! - he will also have to update the if conditional to check the image source - not the anchors source

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if i didn't understand your question correctly.
You want to show/hide the panel when there is clicked on the anchor, when it's clicked also the image should change.

Why not make a layout for the anchor itself and use background url to change it?

```
#hideButton
{
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    display: inline-block;

    background: url('http://png.findicons.com/files/icons/2338/reflection/128/collapse_arrow.png');
    background-size:25px 25px;
}

.reverse
{
    -moz-transform: scaleY(-1);
    -o-transform: scaleY(-1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(-1);
    transform: scaleY(-1);

    //you can place a other image in here.

    margin-bottom: 2px;
}
```

Now i have used mirrored image on click, you can use any image you want.

Now the jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#hideButton").click(function()
    {
        if($("#panel").is(":visible"))
        {
          $('#panel').slideUp('slow'); 
          $('#hideButton').addClass('reverse');
        }
        else
        {

            $('#panel').slideDown('slow'); 
            $('#hideButton').removeClass('reverse');            
        }
    })
})
```

I use *[the premade animation](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/)* SlideUp and slideDown. again, you can change this to your needs.

and finally the HTML:

```
<a id="hideButton" href="#" ></a>
<div id="panel">
    <p>
    Test
    </p>
</div>
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fezZQ/)**